# React: stuck at wait-on at localhost:3000

Tags: reactjs, electron, package.json

I have been trying to implement electron and react together ,with the below `package.json`

```
  {
"name": "loader",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
  "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
  "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
  "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
  "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-countup": "^6.3.1",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
  "react-idle-timer": "^5.4.2",
  "react-loader-spinner": "^5.3.3",
  "react-rnd": "^10.3.7",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.4.0",
  "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
  "react-spring": "^9.5.3",
  "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
  "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"main": "public/main.js",
"homepage": "./",
"scripts": {
  "react-start": "react-scripts start",
  "react-build": "react-scripts build",
  "react-test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
  "react-eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "electron-build": "electron-builder",
  "release": "yarn react-build && electron-builder --publish=always",
  "build": "yarn react-build && yarn electron-build",
  "start": "concurrently \"cross-env BROWSER=none yarn react-start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000/ && electron .\""
},
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": [
    "react-app",
    "react-app/jest"
  ]
},
"browserslist": {
  "production": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "development": [
    "last 1 chrome version",
    "last 1 firefox version",
    "last 1 safari version"
  ]
},
"devDependencies": {
  "concurrently": "^7.5.0",
  "electron": "^21.2.3",
  "electron-builder": "^23.6.0",
  "wait-on": "^6.0.1"
}
}
```

It is clear that concurrently is being used to run all the commands together at same time. Now when I do `yarn start`, all commands are executed along with the `react-start`, but even after the react is available at `http://localhost:3000` the `wait-on` never executes further and is stucked, eventually the electron never starts.
If tested without `wait-on` then all commands are executed well along with the electron.

Can someone guide on this?

Comment: Hello, have you tried with [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) ?

Comment: nope, but still the above code is perfectly fine without `wait-on`, the issue is why `wait-on` isn't executing ahead, or why its not able to detect when `localhost:300` is available. React is taking time in starting up but still, it should do the work when `localhost:300` is available

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same issue.
All I needed to do was to change it from `wait-on http://localhost:3000` to `wait-on http://127.0.0.1:3000`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I was stuck on this for hours thinking it was an incompatibility between Electron and CRA!